# The right way to save big localized text in BlackBerry app

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I need to save 3 localized big text blocks in different languages. Each text block is about 1700 letters.  Is the best way to save it in .rrc files?

Comment: What are you optimizing?  Have you tried dropping the 'big text' into the rrc format to see if it works?

Comment: Yes, it works, my main question is it a right way?

Comment: I edited out the parens again. A key part of your question is the size of the text blocks, so that information should not be conveyed inside parenthesis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically rrc files hold application UI text, which is shorter - on the order of 100 character or so.  1700 is a bit large but if the text fits into the .rrc file without issue, you should be fine.  rrc files are the intended place for translations that match the device's language setting.